# GDB Error C (line number is ??)

Tags: c

Debugging my code keeps resulting in:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Does the ?? mean GDB doesn't know what line it is on? Appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you compile with the `-g` flag?

Comment: It means it doesn't know which function it's in. Try `bt` (backtrace) to see you call stack.

Comment: ^^^ found it, thanks! bt did the trick.